# Display dynamic text boxes upon selecting the particular value from various drop down in the same iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to display the text box when a particular value from the list is selected .I am able to do so but the thing is i have been iterating a loop to print that drop down of list.The Drop down appear twice.How can i make the text box appear  on the specific value selection form both the drop down selection.

Here is my JSP code

```
<s:iterator value="schemePayoutDTO.schemePayoutListFSE" var="fsePay" status="fsePayStatus">
  <s:hidden name="schemePayoutDTO.schemePayoutListFSE[%{#fsePayStatus.index}].paramID" />
  <tr>
    <td>
      <s:textfield name="schemePayoutDTO.schemePayoutListFSE[%{#fsePayStatus.index}].paramValue1" label="%{#fsePay.paramName}"></s:textfield>
      <s:div id="div1" cssStyle="margin-left:15cm; position: relative; bottom:-45px;">
        <s:select style="width: 150px;" id="select" list="schemPayoutTypeList" listKey="payoutType" listValue="payoutTypeVal" name="payoutTypeVal" onchange="showPayoutValue(this.selectedIndex)" />
      </s:div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

I am using the `function showPayoutValue` on select tag of struts to show the text box but that text box is appearing once. I want to show the text box for every correct value selection from the drop down.

Javascript code

```
function showPayoutValue(name){
  if(name=='1' )
       document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='Capping: <input type="text" name="other" />';
  else 
       document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='';
}
```

Here is the screen shot of what i am doing.Also beside the Usage text box if i am selcting the value Percentage with capping then CApping text box must appear.

[image]

Can someone please help me put for this.

Please suggest me any other way out if any.

I will be very thankful

Comment: Why `jquery` tag, when you haven't used it..

Answer (score 0):

**Few things to note**

---

- Your `iterator` will create duplicate `id`s which is against the rules of `HTML`. **The `id` should be unique per page**.
- When you say `document.getElementById` it will always get the first matching `element` and hence the first `div1` will have the `input` always.
- Replace your `id` with `class` and try to match the `element` which is always `closest` to the `select` element.
- You are also placing `select` element inside `div1` and changing its `innerHTML`. This will actually, as of my knowledge, will remove the `select` element too. So place it outside the `div1` element, probably in a separate `div`

**Changes to be made**

---

***`JSP Changes`***

```
<s:iterator value="schemePayoutDTO.schemePayoutListFSE" var="fsePay" status="fsePayStatus">
  <s:hidden name="schemePayoutDTO.schemePayoutListFSE[%{#fsePayStatus.index}].paramID" />
  <tr>
    <td>
      <s:textfield name="schemePayoutDTO.schemePayoutListFSE[%{#fsePayStatus.index}].paramValue1" label="%{#fsePay.paramName}"></s:textfield>
      <s:select style="width: 150px;" class="select" list="schemPayoutTypeList" listKey="payoutType" listValue="payoutTypeVal" name="payoutTypeVal" onchange="showPayoutValue(this)" /> 
      <!-- Pass element instead of value to identify which element has to targeted -->
      <!-- Keep this outside-->
      <s:div class="div1" cssStyle="margin-left:15cm; position: relative; bottom:-45px;">
      <!--Change id to class and keep this empty-->
      </s:div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

***`JS Changes`***

```
function showPayoutValue(ctrl) {
  var name = ctrl.value;//get the selected value
  var targetDiv=ctrl.parentElement.getElementsByClassName('div1')[0];
  //get Target div relating to its parent
  if (name == '1')
    targetDiv.innerHTML = 'Capping: <input type="text" name="other" />';
  else
    targetDiv.innerHTML = '';
  //You can also use conditional operators instead of if else here as below
  //targetDiv.innerHTML=name==1?'Capping: <input type="text" name="other" />':'';
}
```

***`DEMO`***

---

Assuming `html` will be generated as what given in `DEMO`

```js
function showPayoutValue(ctrl) {
  var name = ctrl.value;
  var targetDiv=ctrl.parentElement.getElementsByClassName('div1')[0];
  if (name == '1')
    targetDiv.innerHTML = 'Capping: <input type="text" name="other" />';
  else
    targetDiv.innerHTML = '';
}
```

```html
<div value="schemePayoutDTO.schemePayoutListFSE" var="fsePay" status="fsePayStatus">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="schemePayoutDTO.schemePayoutListFSE[%{#fsePayStatus.index}].paramValue1"/>
      <select style="width: 150px;" class="select" name="payoutTypeVal" onchange="showPayoutValue(this)">
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
            <option value="4">Option 4</option>
      </select>
      <!-- Pass element instead of value to identify which element has to targeted -->
      <!-- Keep this outside-->
      <div class="div1" cssStyle="margin-left:15cm; position: relative; bottom:-45px;">
        <!--Change id to class and keep this empty-->
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</div>
<div value="schemePayoutDTO.schemePayoutListFSE" var="fsePay" status="fsePayStatus">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="schemePayoutDTO.schemePayoutListFSE[%{#fsePayStatus.index}].paramValue1"/>
      <select style="width: 150px;" class="select" name="payoutTypeVal" onchange="showPayoutValue(this)">
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
            <option value="4">Option 4</option>
      </select>
      <!-- Pass element instead of value to identify which element has to targeted -->
      <!-- Keep this outside-->
      <div class="div1" cssStyle="margin-left:15cm; position: relative; bottom:-45px;">
        <!--Change id to class and keep this empty-->
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</div>
<div value="schemePayoutDTO.schemePayoutListFSE" var="fsePay" status="fsePayStatus">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="schemePayoutDTO.schemePayoutListFSE[%{#fsePayStatus.index}].paramValue1"/>
      <select style="width: 150px;" class="select" name="payoutTypeVal" onchange="showPayoutValue(this)">
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
            <option value="4">Option 4</option>
      </select>
      <!-- Pass element instead of value to identify which element has to targeted -->
      <!-- Keep this outside-->
      <div class="div1" cssStyle="margin-left:15cm; position: relative; bottom:-45px;">
        <!--Change id to class and keep this empty-->
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</div>
```